# How to test Sneakers Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to test the sneakers worker ? The [official wiki](https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/wiki/Testing-Your-Worker) has no information for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work in progress. The page you referenced in your question has been recently updated and now contains some info that you might find useful but you can also check this page: https://github.com/jondot/sneakers/issues/97 for info on how to do integration tests.